# GAE Endpoints error in 1.8.0

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have my GAE cloud endpoints working perfectly with version 1.7.5. They were deployed correctly and everything worked fine.

I update GAE version to 1.8.0 and now the .api is not generated by eclipse. I'm using the exact same code.

I tried to create a new project with one method and it worked perfect.

I also tried to generate the .api manually (looking for clues, some error message) using endpoints.cmd but I always get ClassNotFoundException.

Any ideas??

Thanks

EDIT:
It worked fine before I formatted my PC, I tried with java 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: Thank you all. I had a problem with a class, when I removed it from the service everything worked again. I really think endpoints should leave a log somewhere to see whats the problem.

Comment: There should be an "Error" pane view in Eclipse that sometimes prints out useful information :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using Java 1.6? Because Java 1.7 is not compatible with GAE

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im using Java 1.7. But then why the simple test (1 method) worked fine?

Comment: Please, check whether you have compliance level set to 1.6 in that project. If you compile the code using the compiler compliance level to 1.6 it will work just fine.

Comment: i think gae supports 1.7 now.

Comment: Nope, it does not. I spent roughly 4 hours figuring it out. Did you download the Eclipse plugins using p2?

Comment: Java 7 is now the default for all new applications and existing Java 6 code should still run without modification. What is not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the Google Plugin for Eclipse. To do that, click on "help > Check for updates". This solved it for me. 
GAE supports Java 7, moreover, it is the default version (since 1.8).